# Why the use of the term "snowflaking"?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, terminology, fractal-analysis

I've seen a few places in the literature (in particular in fractal geometry) where we consider a metric space $(X,d)$, and then for $0 < \epsilon < 1$ define a new metric space $(X,d^{\epsilon})$ where:
$$
d^{\epsilon}(x,y) = d(x,y)^{\epsilon}
$$
This new metric space is called an **$\epsilon$-snowflaking** of $X$.

My question: why this particular terminology? Is the new metric somehow reminiscent of snowflakes? Are there some nice illustrations that support this naming convention?

Comment: Probably because of Koch snowflake curves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take an interval, say $[0,1]$, with the usual distance function, i.e. $d(x,y) = |x-y|$.  Now take $\alpha = \log(3)/\log(4)$, and consider the $\alpha$-snowflaked space
$$ ([0,1], d^\alpha). $$
This new space is isometric to the classical von Koch curve, which resembles a snowflake.  Heinonen has a short, but accessible discussion of this in his notes on [Geometric embeddings of metric spaces](https://jyx.jyu.fi/bitstream/handle/123456789/22520/1/rep90.pdf).  My recollection is that he has a more detailed discussion in his book [Lectures on Analysis on Metric Spaces](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387951041), but (thanks to the COVID shutdown), I don't have access to my copy of this book right now.

Citing another source, [Tyson and Wu](https://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/Vol30/tyson.pdf) have the following to say:

> [image]
>
> Our terminology stems from the observation that the classical von Koch snowflake curve $C$, endowed with the planar Euclidean metric, is a $p$-snowflake with $p = \log 4 / \log 3$.  Indeed, we may choose $d'(x,y) = \mathscr{H}^p(C_{xy})^{1/p}$, where $\mathscr{H}^p$ denotes the Hausdorff $p$-measure on $C$ and $C_{xy}$ denotes the minimal connected subset of $C$ containing $x$ and $y$.  See Figure 1.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know of any illustrations of snowflakings of $[0,1]$ for different values of $\alpha$?

Comment: @Sambo I have seen such images, but I don't know where to find one right off.  Let me see if I can dig something up.

Comment: Arg... I have a very clear image in my head of a curve which starts on the left looking very much like an interval, and becomes increasingly "crinkled" to the right, as the space is snowflaked more and more.  However, I cannot seem to find that image anywhere... :\

Comment: Shoot! Thanks for looking anyway. If you find it let me know :)